# Why isn't CruiseControl.NET emailing build and test results?

Tags: email, nunit, cruisecontrol.net

I'm using CruiseControl.NET with NUnit and NAnt. I'm trying to get CC.net to send out emails that contain the styled test results and build information. My config file looks like this:

```
<publishers>
        <merge>
            <files>
                <file>C:\Tests\*Results*.xml</file>
                <file>C:\Artifacts\*</file>
            </files>
        </merge>
        <xmllogger logDir="C:\Build Logs" />
        <email from="ContinuousIntegrationServer@test.com" mailhost="mail.test.com">
        <groups>
                <group name="alwaysNotify">
                    <notification>
                        <notificationType>Always</notificationType>
                    </notification>
                </group>
                <group name="notifyOnFail">
                    <notification>
                        <notificationType>Failed</notificationType>
                    </notification>
                </group>
        </groups>
        <users>
            <user name="me" group="alwaysNotify"  address="me@test.com"/>
        </users>
        <xslFiles>
            <file>xsl\header.xsl</file>
            <file>xsl\compile.xsl</file>
            <file>xsl\unittests.xsl</file>
            <file>xsl\modifications.xsl</file>
        </xslFiles>
    </email>
</publishers>
```

When I get an email telling me that the build was successful, there is only this in the body:

```
CruiseControl.NET Build Results for project test (http://CISERVER1/ccnet)
```

Why isn't the build information and the test results included in the body?

Comment: Is there anything in the log? My guess is that one or more of the XSL files can't be found, or is broken...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `<includeDetails>true</includeDetails>` to the email publisher section.

Comment: I've found that using the attribute includeDetails="TRUE" also works. Thanks for the fast response.